# Appropriate exponent for inequality

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, functional-inequalities

Let  consider $1<b<2$, the sets $A=\{ x: |x|\geq2 \} \subset \mathbb{R}^3$, $B=\{x: |x|<2 \} \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ and the expression
\begin{equation}
|x|^{1-b} \chi_{ A}
+
|x|^{2-b} \chi_{ B },
\end{equation}
where $\chi$ denotes the characteristic function.

**Question:** Is there an exponent $f(b)$ such that
\begin{equation}
|x|^{1-b} \chi_{ A}
+
|x|^{2-b} \chi_{ B } \leq |x|^{f(b)}, 
\end{equation}
for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^3$ ?

I already tried with $f(b)=b-2$ but it is wrong. Do you have some idea how to attack the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The answer below was corrected thanks to @user23571113's comment.*

**Yes. Any $f(b) \in [1-b,2-b]$ satisfies the requirements.** For instance, $f(b) = \frac 32-b$ is OK.

We can work in dimension one, renaming $|x|$ to $r \geq 0$. On the one hand, as $r \to 0$, you want that
$$
r^{2-b} \leq r^{f(b)}
$$
which is satisfied if and only if $f(b) \leq 2-b$. On the other hand, as $r \to +\infty$, you want
$$
r^{1-b} \leq r^{f(b)}
$$
which  is satisfied if and only if $f(b) \geq 1-b$.

Comment: I think you mixed up the two sets/cases $A$ and $B$, for small $r$ the remaining term is $r^{2-b}$ and for large $r$ it's $r^{1-b}$, giving us the condition $1 - b \leq f(b) \leq 2 - b.$

Comment: Thank you very much! I had indeed swapped things around. This is now corrected.